# download file from mongo gridfs with python

Tags: mongodb

I have uploaded files to the mongo.But when I want to download from mongo by httpresonse on the web browser,that did not work.

Here is the views.py:

```
    if filename is not None:
    file_ = db.fs.files.find_one({
    'filename':filename
        })
    file_id = file_['_id']
    wrapper = fs.get(file_id).read()

    response =  StreamingHttpResponse(FileWrapper(wrapper),content_type=file_['contentType'])

    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % str(filename)
    response['Content-Length']      = file_['length'] 
    return response
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
self.finish_response()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 126, in finish_response
for data in self.result:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 473, in next
return type(self).__next__(self)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/response.py", line 292, in   __next__
return self.make_bytes(next(self._iterator))
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/util.py", line 30, in next
data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

But when I change the StreamingHttpResponse to HttpResponse,the error is as follow:

```
[30/Jul/2014 17:29:43] "GET /download/cs101/ HTTP/1.1" 200 664
/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py:126: DeprecationWarning: 
 Creating streaming     responses with `HttpResponse` is deprecated.
 Use `StreamingHttpResponse`instead if you need the streaming behavior.
for data in self.result:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
   self.finish_response()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 126, in finish_response
for data in self.result:
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 473, in next
return type(self).__next__(self)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/response.py", line 292, in __next__
return self.make_bytes(next(self._iterator))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/util.py", line 30, in next
data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the `read` method in:

```py
wrapper = fs.get(file_id).read()
```

So you're getting a `str` (assuming Python 2, if 3, you're getting `bytes`). `FileWrapper` needs file like object, which of course `str` is not one.

Try to use:

```py
wrapper = fs.get(file_id)
```

This will return file like object.

OTOH, pymongo's `.get()` returns a GridOut instance, which already supports  [iteration](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/gridfs/grid_file.html#gridfs.grid_file.GridOut.__iter__), so why not try something like:

```py
wrapper = fs.get(file_id)
response =  StreamingHttpResponse(wrapper, content_type=file_['contentType'])
```